# Save the current view of leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, leaflet

I have a map view implemented by leaflet.js, which some options and control. The user adjust the controls and options could update the map view with layers of vector and point. Is there any method to capture the current state of the map view to a PNG image and let user to download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for Leaflet [print/export plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport). But note that usually these plugins require to use [Canvas instead of SVG](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#global-l_prefer_canvas) and to avoid DOM elements (like `L.divIcon` etc.)